# Nokia Maps - Change Circle Coordinates

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I have a relatively simple task:

1. I draw a circle on my map
2. I want to change the position of the circle

Here is the code:

```
var Circle1 = new nokia.maps.map.Circle(new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(49.68385, 8.60468), 2000,{pen: {strokeColor: "F76D", lineWidth: 2}, brush: {color: "#0FF6"}});
map.objects.add(Circle1)
```

Now, I expected this to work:

```
Circle1.set("coordinate", [49.44, 8.44]);
```

It works for some other objects like SVG markers but it doesn't work for a simple circle.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the `Marker` object has a `coordinate` property, the `Circle` object has a `radius` and `center`. You can alter the `center` property as shown:

```
  circle.set("center", [49.44, 8.44])
```